# How to create blender with opencv-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm using opencv3.4 to stitch images with a lot of customization, but `cv.detail_MultiBandBlender` seems only avaiable in opencv 4.x but with 4.x surf is "patented and is excluded". Is there any hack so that I can use blender with opencv-python3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Patented stuff is usually just moved to the `contrib` repository, so you have to clone the original OpenCV repo, then add the `contrib` over and maybe modify a few compile options to get all your required things back and running.

Comment: But I am using python, recompile them seems not enough.

Comment: @NickAllen `pip install opencv-contrib-python` might help?

Comment: Nope, can only see the 'Blender_MULTI_BAND' constant, no idea how things in cpp expose to python.

Comment: I find the pattern: only symbols with CV_EXPORTS_W will be visible from python. And for blenders, it is only added after 4.0.1 by this [commit](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/2fb409b286acb0d16495ddc93326c8bf1944f1aa)